# I need help populating a listview from a remote source in android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I've searched far and wide for this answer and can't seem to find it.

I'm looking to populate a very simple 3 line listview, no more then 5-6 words per line at the most inside of my android app.

I'm  currently using a base adapter and a string array to enable the actual text to show up on the screen.

I want to have the ability to update the information inside of my listview remotely using 
some sort of means whether that's xml, SQLite, plain text, etc and then have that hosted file populate my listview.

Can anyone here help me to figure out how to do this? I'm still pretty new to android development so please go easy on me. Hopefully this question wont be too hard answer and also not too difficult to enable for a newbie like myself.

Comment: since you are keeping you db in remote place, you better change your title as 'populating a listview from a remote source'

Comment: Sorry fuzz but this is a very broad question. Questions like this can not be answered in a constructive way on stackoverflow. Try to break the question down into smaller pieces and try to start with one part of the app like getting the data to the phone. If you then have problems with this code come back and ask for a solution.

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect the changes suggested by Sam Quest and to hopefully make my question more to the point as per Janusz suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the most you're going to ever have in there is just 3 lines of text, I think a SQLite DB may be a bit much for your situation.  I'd look into using a Typed Array.

Here's a link to the Android Dev Guide on this subject:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray

Here's a code sample:

```
public class YourListActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] mTestArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter to contain your items
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        mTestArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.yourArray);    

        // Assign your array to an adapter with your layout file 
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mTestArray);

        // Assign the adapter to this ListActivity
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Just realized that your data will be on a remote server, so this approach may not work for you, but it can still give you an idea of how to take your data once received from your remote server and place it into a ListView.

Comment: Thanks for all the reply's. I'm not even too sure if a SQLite database is needed as the actual text itself is just 3 lines and they are only ever going to be 5-6 words per line at the most. Is there an easier way of doing this?